# Выражение должно иметь тип класса, как исправить?

Tags: c++, классы

Ошибка в стоке:

```
bool kill (Rplane x, Uplane y){
if(x.set < y.set)
    return false;
else
    return true;
}
```

С одним перечислением все работает великолепно, но с двумя уже полная проблема.

```
#include <iostream>



class RU;

enum Rplane {SU6, SU29, SU35};
enum Uplane {F16, F22, F29};

class US{
private:
    Uplane set;
public:
    US (Uplane  value){
        set = value;
    }
    ~US(){}

    friend bool kill (Rplane x, Uplane y);
};

class RU{
private:
    Rplane set;
public:
    RU (Rplane value){
        set = value;
    }
    ~RU(){}
    friend bool kill (Rplane x, Uplane y);
};

bool kill (Rplane x, Uplane y){
    if(x.set < y.set)
        return false;
    else
        return true;

}

int main (){
    SetConsoleCP (1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);

    RU plane_one (SU6);
    US plane_two (F22);

    if (kill(plane_one, plane_two)){
        std::cout << "Американский истребитель лучше" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Российский истребитель лучше" << std::endl;
    }


    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а зачем делать функцию `kill` другом, если в неё и так передаются оба параметра. Что-то тут не так.

Comment: Так и должно быть, пример взят из книги:)

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста язык в тегах.